# How to register multiple nodes to the hub in selenium grid

Tags: selenium, automation, grid

Need to register multiple nodes to the hub, Any help in this regards will be appreciated.Selenium grid to be performed with the same driver object.

This is how my code looks like.

Deriving the class using RemoteWebDriver for Hub instance.

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.Platform;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

import com.project.pages.ExcelConstants;

public class DriverInitializer {

    private WebDriver driver = null;

    public WebDriver getWebDriverFactory() {
        return this.driver;
    }

    /**
     * Returns WebDriver Instance Depending on Parameters browser and Grid d
     * 
     * @param browser
     * @param grid
     * @return
     */
    public WebDriver getDriver(String browser, String grid) {
        if (grid.equals("y")) {
            getWebDriverRemote(browser);
        } else if (grid.equals("n")) {
            getWebDriverLocal(browser);
        }
        return driver;
    }

    /**
     * Creates Local WebDriver Instance
     * 
     * @param browser
     * @return
     */
    public WebDriver getWebDriverLocal(String browser) {
        try {
            if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                        System.getProperty("user.dir")
                                + "\\Drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
                ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
                options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches",
                        Arrays.asList("ignore-certificate-errors"));
                driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
                return driver;
            }
            if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("ie")) {
                System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver",
                        System.getProperty("user.dir")
                                + "\\drivers\\IEDriverServer.exe");
                DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities
                        .internetExplorer();
                cap.setCapability(
                        InternetExplorerDriver.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_BEHAVIOR,
                        "accept");
                cap.setCapability("nativeEvents", true);
                cap.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INITIAL_BROWSER_URL,
                        ExcelConstants.TEST_URL_2);
                cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
                cap.setCapability(
                        InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,
                        true);
                return driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(cap);
            }
            if (browser.equals("firefox")) {
                System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",
                        System.getProperty("user.dir")
                                + "\\Drivers\\geckodriver.exe");
                // Extra code added
                DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
                capabilities.setCapability("acceptInsecureCerts", true);
                // Extra code ended
                return driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return driver;
    }

    /**
     * Creates Remote WebDriver Instance
     * 
     * @param browser
     * @return
     */
    public WebDriver getWebDriverRemote(String browser) {
        DesiredCapabilities cap = null;
        try {
            if (browser.equals("ie")) {
                cap = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
                cap.setCapability(
                        InternetExplorerDriver.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_BEHAVIOR,
                        "accept");
                cap.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INITIAL_BROWSER_URL,
                        ExcelConstants.TEST_URL_2);
                cap.setCapability("nativeEvents", true);
                cap.setBrowserName("internet explorer");
                cap.setPlatform(Platform.ANY);
            }
            if (browser.equals("firefox")) {
                cap = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
                cap.setCapability(
                        InternetExplorerDriver.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_BEHAVIOR,
                        "accept");
                cap.setBrowserName("firefox");
                cap.setPlatform(Platform.ANY);
            }

            if (browser.equals("chrome")) {
                cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();

                cap.setBrowserName("chrome");
                cap.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);

            }

            driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(ExcelConstants.NODE_URL_1), cap);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return driver;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DriverInitializer di = new DriverInitializer();
        di.getWebDriverRemote("chrome");
    }

    /**
     * Implicit Wait
     */
    public void waitForPageToLoad(WebDriver driver) {
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    /**
     * Maximizes the window
     */
    public void maximizeWindow(WebDriver driver) {
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

}
```

I tried using the thread class but unable to implement it using the concept.

Comment: There are a lot of existing tutorials to do this... which ones have you followed and what was the result?

Answer (score 0):

download selenium server stand alone jar from [here](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/)
after that follow below step

1- start hub using below command

```
java -jar "your selenium serverstand-alone.jar file path here" -role hub
```

2- now register your first node with hub-

```
java -jar "your selenium-server-stand-alone.jar file path here" -role node  -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -port 5556 -browser "browserName=chrome, maxInstances=5"
```

3- now start 3rd, 4th etc. by just changing -port and browser value

```
 java -jar "your selenium-server-stand-alone.jar file path here" -role node  -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -port 5558 -browser "browserName=firefox, maxInstances=5"
```

to execute on node using selenium server use **RemoteWebDriver** instead of firefox or chrome driver

for more details description follow below tutorial

https://www.guru99.com/introduction-to-selenium-grid.html